# PHP's preg_match() equivalent in C++?

Tags: c++, preg-match

My question is simple.
Is there a PHP's preg_match() function equivalent in the C++ STL?

If not, can you tell me an alternative?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`preg_match()` calls code from [libPCRE](http://www.pcre.org/). If you want the equivalent of `preg_match()`, then you must use that library.

Alternatively, if you just need the feature of regular expression matching (PCRE or not), there is also the `Boost::regex` library mentioned in another answer.

If your compiler supports the new versions of the standard (C++11 or later), then it probably also includes the new [standard regular expression library.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) The Standard includes support for ECMAScript syntax (which is very similar to, and based on, PCRE) as well as a few others.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the *exact* equivalent to preg_match(). ;-)

Comment: Boost.regex supports multiple regex formats. The default format is Perl compatible and hence compatible with PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out. I'm now using Poco-Foundation's RegExp class that also uses PCRE. http://pocoproject.org

Comment: Me neither. /me bows to Ferruccio.

Answer (score 6):

STL (till C++0x) does not supports regular expressions. But you can use `boost::regex` library.

Comment: Docs located at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html